# Is there solution for equation which is recursive?

Tags: vectors, recursion

I have this following vector equation:$$\vec x = \vec x_0 + (1/2) * f(\vec x, t)t^2$$
where $\vec x$ has initial value when first fed into function $f$. All vectors are 3 dimensional and function $f$ returns an 3 dimensional vector. This function is intended to replace current recursive compution method, in order to get exact results instead as we cannot iterate over infinitely small numbers required for $t$.

Currently I start with $t = 0$ and I increment it by smallest possible value for each iteration. I first feed the $t = 0$ and $\vec x = \vec x_0$ ($\vec x_0$ being the starting value) into the function, and then I calculate the initial value for $f(\vec x, t)$ , and then I calculate the first output of above function. For next cycle I increment $t$ with very small constant value until it reaches the desired value in order to get $\vec x$ as function of $t$. This obviously leads into errors especially when used for bigger values of $t$.

Is there any way to reformulate this expression into solvable form, such that $\vec x$ depends on $t$, $\vec x_0$ and initial value of $\vec x$? I tried using differential equations to solve this, but I couldn't figure it out. I asked my maths teacher, but he too couldn't figure anything out. If this equation cannot be solved directly, then is there any other way to get exact result without using iteration? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Numerically Root solving for x given t and $x_0$. At this time this is the only approach I can see..

Comment: @mvw I want to solve this equation such that I can get the value for $\vec x$ as function of $t, \vec x_0$ also at the beginning $\vec x = \vec x_0$

Comment: @mvw my f only returns one possible vector as a result of multiple summation of various other 3d vectors, so this comes to single solution, right?.

Comment: @mvw What do you mean with $t_n$? It isn't in my equation at all.

Comment: @mvw And by single valued you mean taking in a single parameter?

Comment: @mvw Ok. My $f$ function returns a vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $t=1$, the equation would be 
$$
x = x_0 + \frac{1}{2} f(x, 1)
$$ 
This is a fixed point equation
$$
x = \Phi(x)
$$ which might be (depending on $f$) have zero, one or more solutions $x$.

For different $t$ values the function $\Phi$ changes, so we could write that
as a familiy of equations:

$$
x = \Phi_t(x)
$$

For general $f$, meaning you don't specify $f$ any further, nothing can be simplified, you will end up applying one of the methods to solve these kind of equations, like fixed-point iteration or some geometrical method.

#### Example

$$
f(x,t) = t \, x^2 
$$
and $x_0 = 0$. So we have to solve the fixed-point equation
$$
x = \frac{1}{2} x^2
$$
From the plot below

[image: fixed point problem]

we take the solutions $x=0$ and $x = 2$ and because we know $f$ we are quite sure there are no more solutions around.

#### Example 2

Having higher dimensional vectors does not change the sitatuation dramatically. Let us go to 2D, because here we can still use a plot to spot solutions:

$$
f([x,y]^T,t) = t \, [x + y, x - y]^T 
$$

again for $t = 1$. We now have the vector equation
$$
[x,y]^t = \frac{1}{2} [x+y, x-y]^T = \Phi([x,y]^T)
$$

Comment: My function $f$ is two valued function, taking a 3d vector and real number and it returns 3d vector.

Comment: So there is solution for this after all, when $f(\vec x , t)$ is known function?

Comment: Basically it's just a long addition of vectors derived from the input vector $\vec x$ plus some constants and some are formed and added to the output with help of variable $t$

Comment: lets say $f(\vec x ,t) = \vec x * t + \vec x * 6 + \vec x + 8\vec i$

Comment: That would lead to $x = x_0 + (t^2/2) ((6+t) x + 8 i)$ which is more or less $x = a x + y$ for some scalar constant $a$ and some vector constant $y$. It can be solved by $x = (1/(1-a)) \, y$.

Comment: Can we solve this equation though?

Comment: $a = (t^2/2)(6 + t)$ and $y = x_0 + (t^2/2)8 i$. Thus $x = (1/(1 - (t^2/2)(6+t))) (x_0 + (t^2/2)8 i)$.

Comment: Oh, thank you for your help. Now I finally get it :D

Comment: That was the lucky case, with your $f$ being linear in $x$.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{pseudo-code:}$

1. $t_n = t_{n-1} + dt$
2. find $x_n$ as the solution to $$F(x_n,t) = x_n - x_{0} - \frac{1}{2}f\left(x_n,t_n\right)t_n^2 = 0$$
3. repeat until you reach $t_N$

I apologize for the awful presentation.

To root solve you can use Newton method for multiple functions that equation to zero i.e. each component.

Comment: Why did you put all those $_n$ there?

Comment: Because you computing the evolution of $\bf{x}$? So for each time step you compute the new vector thus I thought using the subscript is appropriate here.

Comment: I don't want to step $t$ (if you mean that by increment), because it gives errors. Also I want to be able to compute just $F(\vec x_0 ,t)$ and get correct $\vec x$ as result.

Comment: Also what do you mean with $dt$? Differentation over $t$?

Comment: It is similar to what @mvw has stated. It is basically for every t you can solve the above equation for the required $\vec_x$. So the dt was just the increment to the next value of t you want to solve.. This getting $\vec x(t)$. But I may if mis interpreted the question.

Comment: So there is no way to solve this as $F(\vec x_0 ,t)$?

Comment: You may be able to do some sort of implicit scheme. But if we look at a simple case $$x = x_0 - xt^2$ Solve for x in the case where you let the rhs be only dependent on $x_0$ and the case where it is solved as is..